# format json not valid using jsonResponse in symfony

Tags: json, symfony

i'm using in my symfony project Json data and in my controller i return data with New Response , it would be like :

```
{"cn":"dvsdvsdvergfe","gender":"M","fgff":"data","mail":"sino@hotmail.fr","sn":"SINO","uid":"sino"}
```

but if i return my data in a JsonResponse i have data like this format :

"`{\"cn\":\"dvsdvsdvergfe\",\"gender\":\"M\",\"fgff\":\"data\",\"mail\":\"sino@hotmail.fr\",\"sn\":\"SINO\",\"uid\":\"sino\",
}"`

the controller :

```
public function getUserByUidAction($uid)
    {
        $url = self::Ws_URL . self::Ws_PORT . self::Ws_GetUserByUID . $uid;
        $headers = array() ;
        $headers[] = "auth_token: ".self::Ws_Token ;
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json" ;
        $arrContextOptions=array(
            "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
            ),
            "http" =>array(
                "method" => "GET",
                "header" => "auth_token: ".self::Ws_Token
            )
        );

        $response   = file_get_contents($url, true, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

       $viewHandler = $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler');
       $view = View::create($response);
       $view->setFormat('json');
       return $viewHandler->handle($view);

        return New Response($response) ;

    }
```

what is happened ?

Comment: can you post the return code?

Comment: you can check now , and i want to say that the $ reponse is a json data not array or object data

Comment: Is `$response` a string (containing the json)? It might need to be an actual object, so `$response = json_decode(file_get_contents(..` could do the trick

Comment: yes , it's true